# Cucumber tags are not being recognised

Tags: ruby, testing, tags, cucumber, bdd

I have a silly and strange problem.
I have taken over a test suite from a colleague which is BDD-Cucumber-ruby based.
There are few tags on top of the feature file, which work.

```
@webview
Feature:
  As a product owner
  I want to blah blah
  So that blah blah
```

1. If I add a tag on top of the scenario, its not recognised.

   ```
   @runagain
   Scenario: Sign in
   Given..
   When ..
   Then..
   ```

and when I run..

```
D:\application\tests\cucumber>cucumber -p default -t @runagain
Using the default profile...
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.003s
```

Update:
cucumber.yml

```
<% run_without_these_tags = "--tags ~@wip --tags ~@manual --tags ~@out_of_scope --tags ~@ignore --tags ~@pending" %>
<% overnight_tags = "--tags ~@wip --tags ~@manual --tags ~@out_of_scope --tags ~@ignore" %>
<% require_features_directory = "-r features" %>
<% publish_to_testrail = "--format Cukerail::Sender --out dummy --format pretty" %>

default: <%= run_without_these_tags %> <%= require_features_directory %> --format pretty
```

This is the silliest of the queries I've posted. But this is bugging me and may be someone can help point me to the simple change I need to do/ a mistake to undo.

Comment: are feature level tags working?

Comment: Does your profile default overrides your @runagain tag? I am not sure about precedence of these configurations...

Comment: Does the test run if you try ```D:\application\tests\cucumber>cucumber -p default -t @runagain -t @webview```?

Comment: What's in your default profile? It will help to see it, as it could be restricting the scenario tag.

Comment: The existing feature level tags work. But I cant add something alongside and make it work.
Added the default profile lines in the description.

Comment: Weird. There isn't anything obvious here to cause this issue. The profile and feature tags worked on trying it out locally. So I can only suspect that there is something more hidden in the code / hooks causing this.

Comment: Also worth checking if the encoding of your cucumber.yml file is correct on the windows machine, and not messing it up to ignore the require for features directory. What happens when you execute cucumber -p default -t @runagain -r features ?